# xRDP - how to view all running sessions

Tags: remote, xrdp

I am new to xRDP..and to Linux from the admin point of view..

I have installed xRDP and xfce4 desktop and I am able to connect with Microsoft RDP
To my Ubuntu 14.04 x 64 bit desktop / server.

My question is, how can I see (as administrator) all sessions that are currently running and disconnected ? 
Is there some solution for this ?  something similar to  the remote desktop manager of windows,
That allows to  see all sessions that are running and disconnected, and that can be managed by the administrator (log off, send a msg, disconnect etc.)

I looked over the internet but didn’t find something like this.

Thank you very much

og11

Answer (score 6):

You could try to use the xrdp-sesadmin command line. Reading around, it seems that this utility can be used to manage running xrdp session.  I never tried this so I do not know if this would work for you.

You can also try to use the ps utility, from a terminal type something like this:

```
ps -ef | grep vnc 

ps -ef h | grep vnc | grep `whoami`
```