# How to find the Disconnected Xrdp sessions?

Tags: command-line, 22.04, scripts, remote-desktop, xrdp

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04 with Xrdp enabled. I need a list of disconnected sessions (Users can often use the "X" to close the RDP session (therefore disconnect but not logout)).

I went through below solution but it couldn't retrieve any disconnected session's data.

https://gist.github.com/OllieJones/27592fb5660a446dccff092a0c029d11

Can anyone help me with some command that can fetch the disconnected sessions with SessionId and username.

Comment: You also posted this in [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78191320/how-to-find-the-disconnected-xrdp-sessions) with exactly the same content. There was an answer to a [similar question](https://askubuntu.com/a/745283/307670) on AU but there was no indication that it worked on that occasion. If it works for you, consider upvoting that answer to help others in the future.